Why does a trained CatBoost model need to provide training Pool if there are categorical features?
For many methods in CatBoost, for example:

plot_tree(tree_idx, pool=None)has an optional argument of pool. This argument becomes required if there are any one-hot encoded categorical variables.

save_model also has an optional pool argument, accompanied by a note:
The model can be saved to the JSON format without a pool. In this case it is available for review but it is not applicable.


Why after fitting a model, do we need to lug around the entire original training data (which could possibly be huge)?
If I want to draw one classification tree from a fitted model, why would we have any need for all the original data?
As an experiment, I made some fake data, and was able to get plot_tree to function, with some problems. If my fake data did not contain the values of the one-hot categoricals that was present in the tree, this would cause an error.
So simply creating a fake dataset, which has all the possible one-hot categorical values somewhere in the data, is enough to create the tree plots.
If all that is needed is the set of unique categorical values, why not save them along with the model? Since the variables are one-hot categoricals, they should not have too many distinct values. If we are really concerned with model size, perhaps there could be an option in save_model that saves these extra pieces of information, instead of forcing users to keep the entire training dataset (possible huge), just to provide this small bit of information.
I am asking this as a question, not as a feature request, because I am not sure that my understanding of the need for a pool is correct.
Here is an example of what I tried:
After training a model, where I had now discarded the training data, I wanted to see the trees of the model. There were two one-hot features, (call them a and b).
In my case the features took integer values. I just created a fake database with all zeros. I filled my one-hot columns with the possible one-hot values. Passing this as the pool argument to plot_tree seemed to be enough to get a plot without errors. Checking against the correct answer, it seemed to be identical.
onehotvalues = {'a':np.arange(154), 'b':[1,2,3]}
allfeatures = ['winCount'] + Xfeatures

maxlen = max([len(v) for v in onehotvalues.values()])
train = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros([maxlen, len(allfeatures)]), columns=allfeatures)
for k, v in onehotvalues.items():
    train.loc[:len(v)-1, k] = v
train = train.astype({k:int for k in onehotvalues.keys()})
train_pool = cb.Pool(train[Xfeatures], label=train.winCount, cat_features=list(onehotvalues.keys()))
model.plot_tree(20, train_pool)


